# Высота div с контектом равна 0

Tags: css, html

[image: Обратите внимание на css hero & product]

Когда я прописал всё в px всё работает и всё ок.Когда прописываю в % элементы див теряют свою высоту и через консоль я вижу что высота 0.
Как решить этот трабл?
overflow: hedden; пробовал ничего не меняется.

Comment: Приведите проблемный код вместо скриншота

Answer (score 5):

Если указываете величину в процентах, то от чего, от какой величины этот сам процент?
Либо укажите в родительском блоке height: 100%;
либо

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

А вообще как правильно сказала Елена, высота блока либо указывается явно в пикселях, либо зависит от содержимого

Answer (score 2):

1. Для демонстрации кода его пишут тут, либо используют online редакторы:

   - [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output),
   - [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/),
   - [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/),

     а не прикрепляют скрин кода.
2. Проценты используют, когда есть относительно чего, относительно внешнего блока. Однако и это не всегда действует. В основном высота блока зависит от содержимого, если не задано явно в px.

   [Из спецификации CSS 2.1 пункт 10.5.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height):

   > Если высота внешнего блока вычисляется по содержимому, то высота в %
   >   не работает, и заменяется на height:auto. Кроме случая, когда у
   >   элемента стоит position:absolute.

   [Полезная СТАТЬЯ](https://learn.javascript.ru/height-percent)

   **ПРИМЕР:**

   ```css
   /* Внешним блокам задана высота */
   body,
   html {
     height: 100%;
   }


   nav {
     width: 100%;
     height: 11%;
     background: #fefefe;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
   }

   .hero {
     height: 80%;
     background: #ccc;
   }

   .product {  
     height: 10%;
     background: #a33;
   }

   .footer {
     height: 10%;
     background: #030;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <nav></nav>
   <div class="hero"></div>
   <div class="product"></div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
   ```

Comment: wh всё решило проблема решена.Спасибо

Comment: @GarryDaam, значит данный ответ подошёл, или ты сам решил свою проблему?